# weighted.mean, summarise() and across()

Tags: r

I would like to aggregate the following dataframe (variables y and z) by number and weight it by "weight". This works as follows:

```
df = data.frame(number=c("a","a","a","b","c","c"), y=c(1,2,3,4,1,7),
                z=c(2,2,6,8,9,1), weight =c(1,1,3,1,2,1))


aggregate = df %>%
  group_by(number) %>%
  summarise_at(vars(y,z), funs(weighted.mean(. , w=weight)))
```

Since summarise_at should not longer be used, I tried it with across. But I wasn't successful:

```
aggregate = df %>%
  group_by(number) %>%
  summarise(across(everything(), list( mean = mean, sd = sd)))

# this works for mean but I can't just change it with "weighted.mean" etc.
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We can pass the anonymous function with `~`.  By checking the `summarise_at`, the OP wants to only return the summarisation of columns  'y', 'z', i.e. using `everything()` would also return the `mean`, `sd` and `weighted.mean` of 'weight' column as well which doesn't make much sense

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  group_by(number) %>%
   summarise(across(c(y, z), 
   list( mean = mean, sd = sd,
            weighted = ~weighted.mean(., w = weight))), .groups = 'drop')
# A tibble: 3 x 7
#  number y_mean  y_sd y_weighted z_mean  z_sd z_weighted
#  <chr>   <dbl> <dbl>      <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl>      <dbl>
#1 a           2  1           2.4   3.33  2.31       4.4 
#2 b           4 NA           4     8    NA          8   
#3 c           4  4.24        3     5     5.66       6.33
```

Often, the `mean` and `sd` works well when there are no `NA` elements.  But if there are `NA` values, we may need to use `na.rm = TRUE` (by default it is `FALSE`.  In that case, the lambda call would be useful to pass additional parameters

```
df %>%
  group_by(number) %>%
   summarise(across(c(y, z), 
   list( mean = ~mean(., na.rm = TRUE), sd = ~sd(., na.rm = TRUE),
            weighted = ~weighted.mean(., w = weight))), .groups = 'drop')
```